# Trying to use Sharepoint designer 2013, but only get html editing options

Tags: 2013, calendar, designer

Fairly new to sharepoint, so this may be a dumb question, but I can't seem to find any information on my issue. I have a site created, and When I go to site pages, the default site page that's been created "home.aspx" has no editing options, and when I click edit, it goes into HTML. I'd really rather not mess around with CSS and HTML, and I've seen people editing outside an HTML editor in sharepoint designer. Worst case scenario, I'll just edit it from the browser, but I'd really like to know how to add objects such as a calendar and other apps like Excel directly onto the page from Sharepoint Designer.

Comment: oooops http://blog.visualsp.com/sharepoint-designer-2013-data-view-web-part-list-view-web-part-design-view-is-gone/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read all about it in,

[SHAREPOINT DESIGNER 2013 DESIGN VIEW IS GONE!](http://blog.visualsp.com/sharepoint-designer-2013-data-view-web-part-list-view-web-part-design-view-is-gone/)

special attention to

> The design view technology is not as up-to-date as the current
>   Internet Explorer. In addition, code view is much more widely used
>   than design view. Design view cannot support the new tags in HTML5 and
>   new cascading style sheets that are used in SharePoint 2013 Preview.

[image]